# Dynamically sorting a table using django

Tags: python, django

Alright, this is my first post so go easy on me :D.

I'm new to working with Django. I'm trying to set a default sort on data in a html table using a django url builder. The data is being dynamically pulled from a JSON.

First, here is my 'sorting' function. I don't want to put everything on here, but assume I have all the dependencies and references right.

```
class TripList(LoginRequiredView, FilterMixin, ListView):
    model = Trip
    filter_class = TripFilter
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(TripList, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        sort_by = self.request.GET.get('sort_by')
        order = self.request.GET.get('order')
        sort_field = '%b %d, %Y'
        if sort_by == 'start_date':
            sort_field = 'datetime.date'<-----------------------------
            qs = super(TripList, self).get_queryset().order_by(
                       sort_field)
        if order == 'desc':
            qs = qs.reverse()
        return qs
```

The biggest blocker for me is that I don't know how I should refer to this line that I'm pointing to. How should I refer to my widget name? I also can't find any documentation on django ids, could anyone direct me? Here is an example skeleton of what I'm trying to do. http://www.robgolding.com/blog/2012/11/17/django-class-based-view-mixins-part-2/

Comment: i believe `order_by()` takes a column name. looks like you should just be able to use `order_by('start_date')`? or is that not the problem?

Comment: Your view parent classes have wrong naming - LoginRequiredView has to be LoginRequiredMixin - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/mixins/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/

Comment: `'datetime.date'` sounds like a data type, not like a field name on a Model.

Comment: @castis are you talking about calling order_by in the url builder?

Comment: @dmitryro look at the link I gave at the end of my post. I only need a listview parent for this function

Comment: you provide a sort criteria 'datetime.date' while it's a type and not a name the model you're calling knows about - it has to be a field name, like in the example in your link it's widget_name which is a legitimate field